# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface in python

Tags: typeerror

I'm having this error in a python script:

> TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

The line that is generating the error is

```
username = cred_file.readlines()[0].split(';')[0]
```

I'm a python beginner, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running a python 2 script with python 3. Python 3 now returns `bytes` no longer `str` when reading from a binary stream.

3 choices:

1. run it with python 2. That if you don't have the rights/time to adapt the script, not recommended as python 3 is becoming more and more the norm.
2. change your code to insert a `decode` function (it will continue to work in python 2):

`username = cred_file.readlines()[0].decode().split(';')[0]`

If file is opened in read/binary mode, `readlines` returns a list of `bytes` not `str`. You have do decode the `bytes` into a `str` to apply str methods.

3. open the file in "r" instead of "rb". `readlines` then returns a list of str and your code will work. Sometimes it can be problematic on windows because of need to preserve the carriage return (`\r`) chars, so look out for side effects in your code.

Note: `cred_file.readlines()[0]` is a questionable construction: you're reading the whole file lines, and drop all the lines but the first. Not very efficient I/O and CPU wise.
Prefer that: `cred_file.readline()` which is equivalent to read the first line.
If you need to read all the lines for further processing, then store the result of `readlines` in a list.